# Hilt can not cast ContextImpl to Application

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-context, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt and recently had a strange problem. For a limited number of devices, I encounter the following error.

```
*dagger.hilt.android.internal.modules.ApplicationContextModule.provideApplication
ApplicationContextModule.java, line 45
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to 
android.app.Application*
```

`ApplicationContextModule` generated by Hilt:

```
/** Provides a binding for an Android BinderFragment Context. */
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
public final class ApplicationContextModule {
  private final Context applicationContext;

  public ApplicationContextModule(Context applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Provides
  @ApplicationContext
  Context provideContext() {
    return applicationContext;
  }

  @Provides
  Application provideApplication() {
    return (Application) applicationContext.getApplicationContext();
  }
}
```

> NOTICE: **`ApplicationContextModule`** was generated by Hilt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
   ...
}
```

What I am doing is just create an instance of `RootWarninginViewModel` (which is annotated with `@ViewModelInject`)

```
class RootWarningViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
   ...
) : ViewModel() {
```

This is what I am actually doing:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RootWarningActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: RootWarningViewModel by viewModels()

}
```

**And here is the complete crash log:**

```
***dagger.hilt.android.internal.modules.ApplicationContextModule.provideApplication ApplicationContextModule.java:45
dagger.hilt.android.internal.modules.ApplicationContextModule_ProvideApplicationFactory.provideApplication ApplicationContextModule_ProvideApplicationFactory.java:34
*.app.DaggerMyApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ActivityRetainedCImpl$ActivityCImpl.provideFactory DaggerMyApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:6658
*.app.DaggerMyApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ActivityRetainedCImpl$ActivityCImpl.getActivityViewModelFactory DaggerMyApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:6663
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.getActivityFactory DefaultViewModelFactories.java:50
*.ui.splash.Hilt_RootWarningActivity.getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory Hilt_RootWarningActivity.java:61
-$$LambdaGroup$ks$bK8-QGfmFwPkSFGulNZ22qySm7s.a -.java:28
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue ViewModelLazy.java:52
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue ViewModelLazy.java:41
*.ui.splash.RootWarningActivity.getViewModel RootWarningActivity.java
*.ui.splash.RootWarningActivity.getViewModel RootWarningActivity.java:11
*.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate BaseActivity.java:74
*.ui.splash.Hilt_RootWarningActivity.onCreate Hilt_RootWarningActivity.java:31***
```

Comment: could you solve the issue? any solutions?

Comment: could you solve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet

Comment: @setaremaghari you can check my answer, I hope it will help to fix  the issue

Comment: @waqar you can check too :)

Answer (score 3):

it's a known bug and the [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2672) in GitHub is closed already but the app will still crash if the `Application` class overrides `getApplicationContext()` like below:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application() {

override fun getApplicationContext(): Context {
    return super.getApplicationContext().updateContextResources()
}
```

in my case the problem was in `updateContextResources()` function

```
fun Context.updateContextResources(): Context {
    Locale.setDefault(localeFromPreferences)
    val locale = Locale.getDefault()

    if (currentLocale == locale && this is Application) {
        return this
    }

    val resources = resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.setCurrentLocale(locale)

    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
        this
    }
}
```

`createConfigurationContext(configuration)` returns `ContextImpl` instead of `Application`, this cause the crash.

Here is my hotfix(new context will be created only when the current one is not Application):

```
return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && this !is Application) {
    createConfigurationContext(configuration)
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    this
}
```

Comment: You're right @Andriy. I'm using local-change-helper too

Comment: @dariushf you can add local-change-helper  library  to the project as a module and add fixes like in the answer or create an issue on the GitHub page so the author will be able to fix this shortly

Comment: Thank you @AndriyD. It solved my problem. I am also using locale-helper-android library.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the argument in the constructor of the module and request the application `Context` to be provided by hilt itself. So you can safely cast it to `Application`. Maybe some of the manufacturers return different context when you call `getApplicationContext()` on the actual application context.

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
public final class ApplicationContextModule {

 @Provides
  Application provideApplication(@ApplicationContext application: Context) {
    return (Application) application;
  }
}
```

`ApplicationComponent` is already seeded with application context. You don't have to provide functions for that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the question, you want the `ApplicationContext`, right?
 Hilt provides a way to get the `Context` by calling

```
@ApplicationContext context: Context
```

I used it with lots of APIs and devices and never had any issues.

Comment: I have not any problem with context. it's crashing because I'm recreating the application context on startup with new forced local.